# Trouble Formatting My Header In CSS

Tags: html, css, background

I want my background image to be top centered with a black background extending 30% of the page Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" text="type/css" href="../css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
.header {
    background: url(../images/header_background.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: Do you want the black background to be 30% on the left 30% on the right?

Comment: try adding `padding-top:30%;` to your .header css.  check http://jsfiddle.net/1vLmx26d/